# ¿Cómo obtener datos completos de la URL sin que afecte otros parámetros en la URL?

Tags: php

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
example.com/video.php?player=https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195
```

Yo deseo obtener los valores que contiene `player`, empleando el método `$_GET` de la siguiente manera:

```
$url = $_GET['player'];
```

Voy a obtener solo el siguiente resultado:

```
https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg
```

Mientras que esto otro no lo voy a poder tener, porque va estar separado mediante esto `&`

```
&e=1614565195
```

Entonces, como puedo obtener de manera completa este valor, sin importar los parámetros que tenga la URL, lo que deseo es obtener todo lo que inicie desde `player=`:

```
https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías obtenerlo combinando las siguientes funciones de PHP:

- **[`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)**: La cual devuelve parte de una cadena.
- **[`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php)**: Que encuentra la posición de la primera ocurrencia de un substring en un string
- **[`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php)**: La cual obtiene la longitud de un string.

Por ejemplo:

```
#El dato obtenido desde $_GET
$url = "video.php?player=https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195";    

#Cadena a partir de la cual extraeremos
$find='player=';
$str = substr($url, strpos($url, $find) + strlen($find));
echo $str;
```

**Salida:**

```
https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195
```

---

También podrías usar [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php). Dado que esta función crea un array usando como separador el dato que le indiques en el segundo parámetro, podría ser interesante si quieres recuperar también el valor `video.php`.

```
$url = "video.php?player=https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195";
$find='player=';
$parts=explode($find,$url);
echo $parts[1]; #video.php estaría en $parts[0]
```

**Salida:**

```
https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195
```

Comment: lo que sucede es que ese parámetro yo debo rescatarlo desde la URL, y así no puedo `$url = $_GET['player'];`

Comment: Si el dato está en la URL, entonces puedes usar `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, que te dará todo lo que hay a partir de `?`.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar `parse_url` y `parse_str` para obtener los valores de la url por separado, ingresas esos valores en una variable y luego muestras según lo que necesites, por ejemplo.

```
<?php

// Ingresamos la url en una variable
$url = 'video.php?player=https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg&e=1614565195';

// Parseamos la url para obtener el path y el query
$url_parse = parse_url( $url );

// Usamos parse_str para asignar los valores del query en la variable parametros
// esto devuelve un array con el parametro player y el parametro e:
// array (size=2)
//  'player' => string 'https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg' (length=86)
//  'e' => string '1614565195' (length=10)
parse_str( $url_parse['query'], $parametros );

// Ahora ingresamos a parametros['player'] para obtener solo los valores de player
// La resuesta: https://c6d34z8w3zavhqt3.ezcdn483.net:8443/hls/dcgmsy35q.m3u8?s=qm3aTTYK9EvvG8aHlbOGMg
echo $parametros['player'];
```